# Solve the series $\sum\limits_{ n=\lfloor\frac{m}{2} \rfloor}^m \frac1{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The floor function is confusing me a bit.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your confusion? Can you sum from n = 2 to 4 ? How about from n = 3 to 7 ?

Comment: I understand how the floor function works, I'm just confused about how to deal with it in this situation.  I've expanded the the series looking for a general solution in terms of $m$, but I can't seem to find anything concise.

Comment: @textra: You will not find a pleasant explicit formula, because nobody will. What is the context? Is it a good approximation that is needed? (For largish $m$ the sum is about $\ln(2)$.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $n=2k$ is even

$$\sum_{ n=\lfloor\frac{m}{2} \rfloor}^{m} \frac{1}{n}=\sum_{ n=k}^{2k} \frac{1}{n}=\sum_{ j=0}^{k} \frac{1}{k+j}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{ j=0}^{k} \frac{1}{1+\frac{j}{k}}$$

which is a Riemann sum. Can you calculate the corresponding integral?

The case $n$ is odd is either similar, or you can use the fact that you only get an extra term which converges to $0$...

Answer (score 2):

Denote your expression by $f_m$, that is
$$
f_m = \sum\limits_{n = \left\lfloor {m/2} \right\rfloor }^m {\frac{1}{n}} .
$$
If $m$ is even, then
$$
\sum\limits_{n = m/2}^m {\frac{1}{n}} ,
$$
and, as you can easily verify,
$$
f_{m+1} = f_m + \frac{1}{{m + 1}}.
$$
Hence the case $m$ odd follows immediately from the case $m$ even: $f_3 = f_2 + 1/3$, $f_5 = f_4 + 1/5$, $f_7 = f_6 + 1/7$, etc.

Comment: So $f_m$ is...?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. m even $\implies n = \frac{m}{2} = \frac{2k}{2} = k$, m odd $\implies n = \frac{m-1}{2}$ since $\frac{m}{2} = \frac{2k+1}{2} = k + \frac{1}{2}$ for some k.

Edit:

Let $H(m) = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n}$. For even m = 2k, then $\sum_{ n=\lfloor\frac{m}{2} \rfloor}^{m} \frac{1}{n} = H(2k) - H(k)$.

Now H(2k) - H(k) is equivalent to the alternating sum = $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \dots - \frac{1}{2k}$, and so approaches ln(2). This can be proved using induction.

Comment: Right. But I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I edited my post, please check.